# Loading a form in dialog/modal returns an error

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I have a form with a submit button binded to an AJAX callback that opens up a modal with another AJAX form. The modal dialog opens with the form, but the AJAX submit in that modal form isn't submitting. It just flashes the AJAX spinner for a second and then disappears. I'm thinking that the form action is not correct or not set when the new form is loaded?

I get this error in my logs:
`warning  page not found /admin/config/custom_theme/distribution/form_action_cc611e1d?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax`

However, the form in the modal works and submits successfully via AJAX when rendered on its own (not in a modal).

The form with the submit button:

```
 <?php

 /**
   * Form constructor.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The form structure.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Because we have many fields with the same values, we have to set
    // #tree to be able to access them.
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

    // Content type mapping.
    $content_types = [
      'all' => 'All',
      'article' => 'Article',
    ];
    $form['content_type'] = [
      '#type' => 'details',
      '#title' => t('Content Type Filter'),
      '#description' => t('Filter by the content type.'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    ];

    // Submit button with AJAX callback.
    $form['search'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Search'),
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'searchAjaxSubmit'],
        'event' => 'click',
        'progress' => array(
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => 'Searching the Distribution API...',
        ),
      ],
      '#suffix' => '<div class="response-message"></div>',
    ];

    // Send to destination button.
    $form['send-destination'] = [
      '#id' => 'send_destination_btn',
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Send to Destinations'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['use-ajax'],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'sendDestinationModal'],
        'event' => 'click',
        'progress' => array(
          'type' => 'throbber',
        ),
      ],
    ];

    // Attach the library for pop-up dialogs/modals.
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    return $form;
  }
```

This is the AJAX callback for the submit button - it opens up the form in a dialog by calling dialogContents():

```
<?php

/**
 * AJAX callback to open the "Send to Destinations" modal.
 */
public function sendDestinationModal(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  // Attach the drupal.dialog.ajax library.
  $response->setAttachments($form['#attached']);

  $content = DistributionController::dialogContents();
  // Attach the AJAX dialog library.
  $content['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
  // Create an AJAX command that sends the content and opens up a modal
  // dialog with the specified options.
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $title = $this->t('Send to Destinations');
  $options = array(
    'dialogClass' => 'popup-dialog-class',
    'width' => '75%',
  );

  $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));
  // Return the AJAX response.
  return $response;
}
```

The controller method that returns the form in the modal:

```
<?php

/**
 * Gets the content for the dialog.
 *
 * @param array $results
 *   The selected content from the "Search" tableselect.
 *
 * @return array
 *   The rendered markup.
 */
public static function dialogContents($results = '') {
  $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\my_module\Form\SendToDestinationsForm', $results);

  return [
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => render($form),
  ];
  return $build;
}
```

The buildForm for the modal form:

```
<?php

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $options = NULL) {
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

  // The list of content that can be selected to send.
  $form['select_content'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => $this->t('Selected Articles'),
    '#options' => $options,
  );

  // Get the destinations from the configuration manager.
  $config = $this->config('my_module.settings');
  $data = $config->get('my_module_destinations');

  $destinations = [];
  foreach ($data as $destination) {
    $destinations[$destination['url']] = $destination['name'];
  }

  // List of destinations to chooose from.
  $form['select_destinations'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => $this->t('Select Destination(s)'),
    '#options' => $destinations,
  ];

  $form['actions'] = [
    '#type' => 'actions',
  ];

  $form['actions']['send'] = [
    '#id' => 'send_destinations',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Send To Destinations'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'use-ajax-submit',
      ],
    ],
    '#suffix' => '<div class="response-message"></div>',
  ];

  // Attach the library for pop-up dialogs/modals.
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

  return $form;
}
```

This is the callback for the submit button for the modal form:

```
<?php

/**
 * Send to destinations submit callback.
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $url = 'http://www.example.com/';
  $response = DistributionController::searchDistribution($url);

  $serialized_entity = $mapper->getSerializedEntity($response);
  $endpoint = 'http://www.example.com/test/post';

  // Get the Guzzle http client.
  $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
  // Get the CSRF token for use in the POST request.
  $token = $client->get(\Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . '/rest/session/token')->getBody();
  $rest_response = $client->post($endpoint, [
    'body' => $serialized_entity,
    'headers' => [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/hal+json',
      'X-CSRF-Token' => $token,
    ],
  ]);

  $form_state->setCached(FALSE);
  // Rebuild the form.
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Is there something I need to do when getting the modal form? Any help is appreciated!